# Scala - Using Filter to see if the value in one list matches the value in the same index in another list

Tags: scala

Given 2 Lists and using the Filter method, i am required to write a function that will take these 2 lists, filter through them and then compare if the value in one index on one list matches the value in the same index on the other list

Example VVV

```
scala> val list1 = List(1,2,3,10)
scala> val list2 = List(3,2,1,10)
scala> val mn = matchedNumbers(list1, list2)
List(2,10)
```

The method is called "matchedNumbers"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried?

Comment: What is `List(2,10)`? What those numbers mean?

Comment: @talex that is an example result. Based off of list1 and list2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is almost the same as of @talex, only using collect:

```
def matchedNumbers(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]) = 
  list1.zip(list2).collect{case (x, y) if x == y => x}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
def matchedNumbers(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]) = {
  list1.zip(list2).filter { case (x, y) => x == y }.map(_._1)
}
```

Comment: Whenever you see `filter` followed by `map`, think `collect` :)

Comment: @Tim didn't know about it. I think while `collect` is shorter, `filter` and `map` are easier to understand. Partial function are weird :)

Comment: `collect` is more efficient and easier to understand for an experienced Scala programmer. Your solution also uses a partial function :)

Comment: @Tim What is easy is subjective. `collect` itself is more complex then `map` or `filter`, is it more complex than their combination is open question. Maybe it is more idiomatic, but I'm not professional Scala programmer. Technically my solution is using partial function, but it is effectively total, because there is no input which it can't handle.